# RxAlamofire make post call with json body

Tags: swift, swift4, rx-swift, rxalamofire

I want to make post call using RxAlamofire not able to find any method to do so

tried using requestJSON method but there is no paramter to pass post json in

```
 RxAlamofire.requestJSON(.post, url)
```

how to make post call and pass json data to post call in RxAlamofire

Comment: Look into [this](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxAlamofire/blob/master/Sources/RxAlamofire.swift) to find all the methods.

Comment: unable to find how to pass post json. Which parameter as dictionary or json string not clear

Comment: you may want to put the JSON string in parameters?
like request(...,parameters: ["json_str": yourJsonString],...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code

```
  var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://some_url")!)
    //Following code to pass post json 
    request.httpBody = json
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    RxAlamofire.request(request as URLRequestConvertible).responseJSON().asObservable()
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function with proper parameters ancoding

```
public func urlRequest(_ method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod,
                   _ url: URLConvertible,
                   parameters: [String: Any]? = nil,
                   encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default,
                   headers: [String: String]? = nil)
```

Comment: where to pass post json?

Comment: @alphanso this should help you https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#parameter-encoding

Answer (score 0):

amodkanthe's solution works. But its return value is not friendly. So I changed it a litte bit

```
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://some_url")!)
    request.httpBody = jsonData  // jsonData is a Data type
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") // this line is important
    RxAlamofire.requestJSON() //=> returns a Observable<(HttpURLResponse, Any)>, the `Any` type is actually a dictionary
```

p.s. the version I'm using is `RxAlamofire(6.1.1)`

Answer (score -1):

Using jsonEncoding

`RxAlamofire.requestJSON(.post, url, encode: JsonEncoding.default)`

It works for me~